# Zoom image to fit ImageView

Tags: android, gridview

I am making a photo app which uses a `GridView`.
The issue is not all my images are fitting my `ImageView` hence I have a non consistent looking `GridView`.

I was looking at the Google's Photos App which came out with KitKat.
I believe Google employs Zoom to fit `ImageView` for its thumbnails.

Can anyone show me how I can do that as well?
I have tried searching, but to no avail.
All help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute to your ImageView:

```
scaleType="fixXY"
```

It will set the image to fit in size both on x and y axis.

Answer (score 0):

actually the Google Photo and most image apps I have see `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`